# can we display a mapView like google earth(see screens)

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, maps

ok to clarify. i understand that the map data is basically some images grouped in bounding boxes and drawn on a 2d canvas. is it possible to rotate the whole view so that it looks like on the image i posted from google earth, to get a kind of fly-over look? i know that there is a class in adroid used for 3d rotations on images(the camera class [Graphics.camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html))
There was a nice tutorial not long ago from sony-erricson with their 3d listview describing its functionality, but i don't think i can achieve what i need with it. is there a way that a view can be rendered maybe on a GL surface?

i realize that this isn't that simple to do but any suggestions or ideas on the matter can be helpful.

so where do i start?

tnx.
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very straightforward with OpenGL. Use triangles laid out in a huge grid and texture map accordingly, setup a camera and you are done. You even get elevations etc right with heightmapped terrain.